# How do I use the pretty print module to print a list in python?

Tags: python, list, pprint

I've been searching this but I can't find it.
I want to view a list of commands in an organized fashion, so that this:

```
Comandos = ["1: Imprime lista de opciones", "2: Abre la calculadora de dinero"]

pprint(Comandos)
```

Gets printed like this:

```
1: Imprime lista de opciones
2: Abre la calculadora de dinero.
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `pprint`, you can simply `join` them together and `print` them:

```
print('\n'.join(Comandos))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @willem-van-onsem said, you can simply join and it will be all done.

However if you <s>need</s> **HAVE TO** to use pprint you can do this as such:

```
pprint(a,width=max(len(a[0]),len(a[1]))*2)
```

Mind you, it is not optimal (nor recommended) solution.

And more general approach :

```
pprint(a,width=len((max(a, key=len))*2))
```

Additional note:
This appropach will not work when n (n>1) of shortest strings sum to the longest (on length).